# Is it possible to remote connect to SQL Server 2008 database with SQL Server Management Studio 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server Management Studio 2005 R2 in my administrator PC, and SQL Server Management Studio 2008 in the Server PC. Each time I tried to connect to the database server (SSMS 2008), it will throw errors that indicated I have different version of database or the software or else (db instance some said?).

I had search the internet. The most correct solution was to use [Cumulative update package 5](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943656/cumulative-update-package-5-for-sql-server-2005-service-pack-2) for SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2 to connect to 2008.

But my questions is, is there any other solution that doesn't need me to update or install any patch for the SSMS 2005 ? Maybe like tweaks or any other fast solution ? Any comments appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your question is answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103/can-i-use-sql-server-management-studio-2005-for-2008-db

Comment: But seriously, today we have 2017. This is **9 years after 2008 and 12 after 2005**. Uninstall SSMS 2005 and install a newer version (2008, 2012, 2014) if not the latest (2016). Then you'll be able to connect to all previous versions of SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are experiencing the problems that are documented as being fixed by installing that update, then there is unlikely to be another way to fix the problem while still keeping that version of the tool.

You don't say why you'd prefer not to install the update. Are you trying to keep yourself at that backwards level to stay specifically identical to a client installation or do you just not have admin rights on the machine so have to get someone else involved to apply the patch?

If you do have access to install software, another option might be to install SSMS 2016 which these days is distributed (for free) separately of the SQL Server engine and other parts and can be install side-by-side with older versions. SSMS 2016 can be obtained from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

> it will throw errors that indicated

When describing a problem or asking for help it is important not to skimp on details that you have which might give clues to people trying to help. *As such you should provide the text of the error messages you have received, otherwise in this case we don't know if they are the sort of problem the update fixes or indicate another problem that needs a different fix.* Help us to help you.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the comments, actually I wanted to minimize the risk by updating or patching the software using the patch update provided by Microsoft, because I handled a big database, that have no backup, and doing some backup process will takes time.
But anyway, thanks for the suggest, and will discussing this with my collage if updating is the only solution left.

Comment: As SSMS is on your admin machine and not the server, you shouldn't need to do anything on the server never mind anything that would require a full backup beforehand. As the server is 2008 then you won't need to install the 2005 update on it, jus on the connecting client machines. BTW "that have no backup" is a **huge** red flag. I *strongly* recommend that you arrange a backup plan (and preferably an automated backup testing procedure too) as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a SQL Server 2008 instance, the minimum version of SQL Server 2005 must be SP4 9.00.5000

Comment: Could you cite the source of that information?